# Python: how prevent duplication of randomly chosen key/value pair

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

```
def fill2_line1():
    x2 = random.choice(list(twoSyllValues.items()))
    line1.append(x2)

magicList = ([x[1] for x in line1])
            
if 1 in magicList:
    fill2_line1()
    fill2_line1()
    complete_line = line1[0][0] + " " + line1[1][0] + " " + 
    line1[2][0]
    print(complete_line)
```

This is the part in question - the whole program is over 150 lines. It works perfectly as is, but sometimes I'm getting duplicated words. To refine the code, I want to make sure that the key in the first random tuple selection is not duplicated in the next two selected tuples IN that list, line1. The only way I can think of is having another dictionary created after the first word selection and then exclude that key,value pair from new dictionary and then make the next two random.choice calls. I feel like there must be a simpler way, but I just don't have the experience yet.

Comment: can you post sample input  and expected output

Comment: Current output can be: wordA wordB wordA. I want the output to be like: wordA word(anything but A) word(anything but A) where wordA is the first value from a tuple pulled from a dictionary.

Comment: @danno include this info in your question. With proper formatting, it would be easier to understand for us rather in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three ways to solve the problem you are facing. I will write a sample code that you can refer to since I do not know your whole code.

1. Delete the key before the second random.choice calls and adding them back in if you need them. This is somewhat similar to creating another dictionary but more efficient.

```py
def fill2_line1():
    x2 = random.choice(list(twoSyllValues.items()))
    line1.append(x2)
    return x2

magicList = ([x[1] for x in line1])
            
if 1 in magicList:
    deleted_list = []
    # run first random.choice
    deleted_item = fill2_line1()
    deleted_list.append(deleted_item)
    del twoSyllValues[deleted_item[0]]
    # run second random.choice
    deleted_item = fill2_line1()
    deleted_list.append(deleted_item)
    del twoSyllValues[deleted_item[0]]
    complete_line = line1[0][0] + " " + line1[1][0] + " " 
                    + line1[2][0]
    print(complete_line)
    # add the deleted items back in after work is done
    for k, v in deleted_list:
        twoSyllValues[k] = v
```

2. Run random.choice until there is no duplicate item.

```py
def fill2_line1(deleted_set):
    x2 = random.choice(list(twoSyllValues.items()))
    while x2 not in deleted_set:
        x2 = random.choice(list(twoSyllValues.items()))
    line1.append(x2)
    deleted_set.add(x2)

magicList = ([x[1] for x in line1])
            
if 1 in magicList:
    deleted_set = set([])
    fill2_line1(deleted_set)
    fill2_line1(deleted_set)
    complete_line = line1[0][0] + " " + line1[1][0] + " " 
                    + line1[2][0]
    print(complete_line)
```

3. Keep another list just for the random.choice

```py
def fill2_line1(items_list):
    x2 = random.choice(items_list)
    line1.append(x2)
    items_list.remove(x2)

magicList = ([x[1] for x in line1])
            
if 1 in magicList:
    items_list = list(twoSyllValues.items())
    fill2_line1(items_list)
    fill2_line1(items_list)
    complete_line = line1[0][0] + " " + line1[1][0] + " " 
                    + line1[2][0]
    print(complete_line)
```

Hope my answer gave you some ideas!

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I'm so glad that I got my point across and you addressed it so thoroughly. I will try all three solutions tomorrow and see how they run. Awesome!

Comment: Glad to hear that! Please let me know how it goes!

Comment: I got the code to run as predicted! However, I only ended up using a portion of your first idea. When I tried to use this: deleted_item = fill2_line1(), I kept getting this error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. fill2_line1 returns a list datatype. :(
 The first selected word really shouldn't be used again for the rest of program so I ended up writing this: random_select = random.choice(list(syll_values.items()))   for key, value in dict(syll_values).items():
    if key == random_select[0]:
    del syll_values[key]   // Thanks again for the logic ideas!

Comment: Great you found a solution! Please upvote my answer if it helped :) I would appreciate it!

Comment: It said my comment counted but won't be displayed since my reputation or whatnot is only 10 currently. Need 50 to publicly upvote.